# Twilio - usage of alphanumeric sender id

Tags: twilio

I'm wondering the "From" parameter of SMS-Api could be typed in for any ID I want,
if the "Alphanumeric Sender ID" is enabled?
Except some countries such as Saudi-Arabia, which has us need to fill this form. (https://twiliodoer.secure.force.com/SenderId)

I'm not sure about the exact usage from the DOC.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Alphanumeric Sender ID is supported by Twilio in [the countries listed on this page](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133767-International-support-for-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID). You can also choose to [use a Twilio Messaging service which allows you to add an alphanumeric sender ID and a long code number pool to fallback to in countries where alphanumeric sender IDs aren't supported](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133867-Using-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID-with-Messaging-Services).

To use an alphanumeric sender ID, you do have to [upgrade your account  first](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183208-Upgrading-to-a-paid-Twilio-account). Once you have done that you can send messages with an alphanumeric sender ID as the `From` parameter, like this example in JavaScript:

```js
const client = require("twilio")(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);

function sendMessage(to, body) {
  return client.messages.create({
    from: "MYSENDERID",
    to: to,
    body: body
  });
}
```